# How to center a border-width shape properly, relative to its parent input button?

Tags: css

I have a newsletter subscription box which looks like this:

[image]

The form takes the whole width of the parent, and so the button fills up all of the available width.

Using the `before` CSS clause, I'm drawing a small 'arrow' shape on top of the Subscribe button.

The problem is that the arrow is not properly centered, relative to the button. This can be demonstrated by reducing the viewport width. For example, here the problem can be seen:

[image]

The arrow is not properly centered horizontally, relative to the button.

How can I solve this alignment issue ?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/7965p/

**CodePen (JSFiddle is down sometimes):** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qFvbc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To center something that is positioned absolute, and of which you know the exact width, I always do the following:

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -[halve the width of the element]px;
```

So your problem should be solved by adding `magin-left: -12px;` to your `.form-wrapper button:before` selector.

Comment: Good thinking ! Worked out just fine.